# Perl CGI get user's user-agent

Tags: perl

I have Perl CGI pages, (.pl extension). How Can I get a persons raw user agent string? 
 There are ways of doing it in Javascript, (which I have been), though I'd rather move over to completely Perl, rather then having some Javascript and some Perl.

In example, to get a person's IP: $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CGI module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);

print header;
print start_html("Environment");

foreach my $key (sort(keys(%ENV))) {
   print "$key = $ENV{$key}<br>\n";
}

print end_html;
```

Answer (score 9):

User agent is stored in `$ENV{HTTP_USER_AGENT}`

Comment: The environment variables are available even if `CGI.pm` is not used.

Comment: Right. I removed comment about `CGI.pm` from answer.

Answer (score 2):

As people have already mentioned, it's always available in the `$ENV{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` variable. But if you're using CGI.pm, you can also get it by calling the `user_agent()` function.